# Connect to MySQL on Vagrant instance with Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, vagrant, sequelpro

I am running Laravel on Vagrant and I am trying to connect Sequel Pro.

I have just started using Vagrant, I have followed a few tutorials on connecting to Sequel Pro however they were all unsuccessful.

Here is my Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
config.vm.hostname = 'laravel'
config.vm.boot_timeout = 3600
config.vm.box = 'debian-73-i386-virtualbox-puppet'
config.vm.box_url = 'http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/debian-73-i386-virtualbox-puppet.box'

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8500, host: 8500

config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', '1536']
end

config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
puppet.manifests_path = 'puppet/'
puppet.manifest_file  = 'init.pp'
puppet.module_path    = 'puppet/modules/'
# puppet.options      = '--verbose --debug'
end

end
```

From `my.cnf`:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Here is my `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       laravel
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

EDIT:
changed bind address to 0.0.0.0 still does not work 
In Sequel Pro I have

```
MySQL Host: 0.0.0.0
username: root
Password: (mysql password)
SSH Host 0.0.0.0
SSH User: vagrant
SSH Password: vagrant
```

EDIT:
Here is my vagrant hosts file - etc/hosts

This is my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       laravel
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Make sure you remove any public keys from your host machine's known_hosts file that are for the same host (IP Address). This will have happened if you have been using another Vagrant VM with the same IP address.

Answer (score 22):

The issue is that MySQL as you have it setup in `my.cnf` now can only connect via `localhost` within the Vagrant server:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

To enable networking in MySQL, you should change that setting in `my.cnf` to:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

And then restart the MySQL service. Unsure of how that would happen in Vagrant, but in Ubuntu you would enter a command like this:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

You might have to check your MySQL user permissions to ensure that the user within MySQL can actually be used from any IP address—sometimes they are set strictly to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`—as well.

As explained in [the official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html):

> The server treats different types of addresses as follows:
>
> - If the address is 0.0.0.0, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 interfaces.
> - If the address is ::, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces. Use this address to permit both
>     IPv4 and IPv6 connections on all server interfaces.
> - If the address is an IPv4-mapped address, the server accepts TCP/IP connections for that address, in either IPv4 or IPv6 format. For
>     example, if the server is bound to ::ffff:127.0.0.1, clients can
>     connect using --host=127.0.0.1 or --host=::ffff:127.0.0.1.
> - If the address is a “regular” IPv4 or IPv6 address (such as 127.0.0.1 or ::1), the server accepts TCP/IP connections only for that IPv4 or IPv6 address.

That said, exposing MySQL—or any database server—to the world is not advisable. But is acceptable in a case of local development like this.

So if enabling MySQL networking is not an option, you can also use the built in SSH tunneling capabilities in Sequel Pro to connect to MySQL via SSH. Details on all of the different connection types are shown on [the official Sequel Pro site here](http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/what-type-of-connection-do-i-have). But this screenshot sums it up nicely.

Basically you just set your `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` MySQL info as you normally would. But you also add the SSH info you would use to SSH into your server. And Sequel Pro will use that SSH connection to tunnel in & connect to MySQL seamlessly. This might be the better way to handle instead of dealing with MySQL networking & user permission issues.

[image]

For SSH tunneling in Sequel Pro you just need to do the following:

- **Name:** The name you want for the connection.
- **MySQL Host:** The IP address of the MySQL host which should be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
- **Username:** MySQL database username.
- **Password:** The password connected to that MySQL database username.
- **Database:** Optional (database you want to connect to)
- **Port:** Default is 3306 so only change this if you definitely have to set to anything else.

Now here you set the SSH settings for your Vagrant install:

- **SSH Host:** The hostname or IP address of your Vagrant machine.
- **SSH User:** The SSH username to that Vagrant machine.
- **SSH Password:** The password connected to that SSH user.
- **SSH Port:**  Default is 22 so only change this if you definitely have to set to anything else.

Comment: SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |

| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*9F94EDBB4F0262FEA358A0A61F3B5F07FA991E61' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: I am trying to do it with an SSH, I just cant seem to find what is wrong.

Comment: I have been trying with SSH tunneling since yesterday. I cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help, do you think the issue could be im running three vagrant virtual boxs on localhost

Comment: Took me a few shots to overcome my own mental ineptitude, but this was definitely the answer that worked for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

this is my configration:

[image]

Vagrant machine default **ssh user** and **ssh password** all are **vagrant**.

Comment: In my case works SSH User: root, SSH Password: vagrant

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is edit the bind address located here:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Find the bind_address setting which will be set to 127.0.0.0 and change it to 0.0.0.0

After that restart mySQL:

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

The final step is just updating permissions:

```
$ mysql -u root -proot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

Then connect as you normally would (changing port to what ever you set in your vagrant file).

[image: sequel pro settings]

*Note there are security issues here since it's all pretty open but for dev work it's fine.*

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/AlexDisler/mysql-vagrant, it lets you connect without an ssh tunnel (check out install.sh for the specific settings).

Comment: Sweet! i'm new to vagrant and am surprised to not find simple "one off" vagrants like this in Vagrant Cloud... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers didn't work for me until I have tried this:

- Connect to your vagrant instance using `vagrant ssh`
- When just type `passwd` to set a new password. Use password `vagrant` for consistency.

It will connect easily after that steps taken.

Thanks to @hugo at [How do I Sequel Pro with PuPHPet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836246/how-do-i-sequel-pro-with-puphpet)

Answer (score 0):

The answer about the bind-address is right, however I have found that instead of changing the value to 0.0.0.0, it's better to just edit the my.cnf file and comment out the bind-address altogether.

If you do that and then follow the rest of the original answer, you should be able to connect via sequel pro

Answer (score 0):

For me, the vital part was using 0.0.0.0 as MySQL host instead of 127.0.0.1. Everything else is business as usual (using SSH). This works for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below are my screenshot for vagrant connected using mysql workbench from MAC [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to your Vagrant box has to be made via SSH. So if you have connected before, and have made any major changes to your Vagrant box (such as a destroy/rebuild), you may have a new private key and need to refresh your IP address record in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. To do that, open the file in vim and just delete the line that starts with your vagrant box IP address.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `vagrant port` to check the current port forwarding (in case one has several vagrant boxes).

Also if the case is more than one vagrant box the issue could be that a new ssh key must be added to the host's `.ssh/known_hosts` by:

1. commenting the **first vagrant box host** in the host's `.ssh/known_hosts`;
2. adding the **second vagrant box host** through the Sequel Pro test connection dialog;
3. uncommenting the **first vagrant box host** in the host's `.ssh/known_hosts`.

So both vagrant boxes (each one with it's own key) are now known.