# Connecting Database GUI to Vagrant (PuPHPet)

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant, puphpet

I set up Vagrant yesterday using PuPHPet and everything seemed to work fine. I used Querious to connect to the mysql database. However, I didn't save the configuration I used to connect and after doing vagrant up this morning I can't seem to connect no matter what I do.

What I'm trying:

- SSH Host: 192.168.56.101
- SSH User: vagrant
- SSH Pass: vagrant
- SSH key: .../puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa
- SSH port 2222
- Host: 127.0.0.1
- User: username
- Password: password
- Port: 3306

If I try those settings I get

```
> SSH failed to connect to the server 192.168.56.101 on port 2222
> 
> SSH connection failed for an unknown reason. SSH shutdown.
>
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.101 [192.168.56.101] port 2222.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.56.101 port 2222: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.101 port 2222: Operation timed out
```

If I change the SSH host to 127.0.0.1 I get a different error. The remote host's SSH key failed verification.

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/db/Dev/c2t-vagrant/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/db/Dev/c2t-vagrant/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 9c:3a:9a:d0:22:8c:19:05:f2:26:54:d9:62:9e:ba:e4
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
9c:3a:9a:d0:22:8c:19:05:f2:26:54:d9:62:9e:ba:e4.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/db/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/db/.ssh/known_hosts:2
RSA host key for [127.0.0.1]:2222 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I did "vagrant ssh" and went to ~/.ssh and there were three files, authorized keys, id_rsa, and id_rsa.pub. id_rsa matched the key I was choosing, but I didn't immediately recognize what was in the authorized_keys file.

I also tried changing the bind address in the php.ini a la [Connect to MySQL on Vagrant instance with Sequel Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959457/connect-to-mysql-on-vagrant-instance-with-sequel-pro), but I didn't have any luck/didn't understand what that was doing.

I am obviously flying blindly, being new to Vagrant and having a very incomplete grasp on SSH. What type of things should I be trying next to get this working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuPHPet defaults to use port 22 for ssh. Make sure that's what your config.yaml says.

If you've changed it, make sure the port is added to the firewall.

Comment: Well, that is truly an embarrassing waste of time. Thank you for your answer even though I'm so very dumb.

Answer (score 2):

Try using :

```
vagrant ssh-config
```

to find out all the configuration you need for connection.
Check out this link:
[Vagrant and Mysql Workbench](http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2016/02/mysql-workbench-client-with-vagrant-mysql-on-virtual-machine/#comment-166913)