# How do I Sequel Pro with PuPHPet?

Tags: mysql, vagrant, puphpet, sequelpro

I have just set up a virtual machine using Vagrant and Puphpet. I know I have MySQL because I can `mysql` in the command line. I just did a basic install.

I don't know how to set up my sequel pro to get access though. I am using the "Standard" option on the Sequel Pro application (the others are "Socket" and "SSH"). Is that the right one to use? The values I enter are;

Name: awesome
Host: 192.168.56.101
Username: mlovely
Password: mlovely
Port: 9000

Here is my part of my `config.yaml` file that relates to mysql

```
mysql:
  install: '1'
  override_options: {  }
  root_password: root
  adminer: 0
  databases:
    0x04jJcIakVr:
        grant:
            - ALL
        name: dbname
        host: localhost
        user: mlovely
        password: mlovely
        sql_file: ''
```

Not sure where to look or what else to try now.. The error I get on sequel pro is an "Unable to connect or the request timed out" type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put the information on puphpet.com - maybe you missed it

[image: it's on the gui]

Comment: +1 Brilliant @Juan Treminio - I found this answer to work for my setup. Thank you. I agree with drj201 that this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Tip: If you trying this and are having issues e.g. error message: "The SSH tunnel has unexpectedly closed." and in the log detail you see something like: "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" "IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!" "Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!" then a solution has worked for me and could work for you is to remove the entry for your VM IP address in your known_hosts file - e.g. on MacOS this is /Users/yourusername/.ssh/known_hosts - delete the line for your VM then try connecting again.

Comment: The reason why the tip in my above comment would work is because the entry in known_hosts is for an old VM and you deleted this VM (via vagrant destroy or from the Virtual Box UI) and then built a new VM (via vagrant up) with the same Vagrant/Puphpet manifest. The building of the new VM by Vagrant would include creating a new ssh key/host details which would mismatch those in your known_hosts file (which were for the old VM). On building the new VM, you should find the entry for your new VM IP address (the same IP as the old VM) had been added.

Comment: Also, if you are seeing an error about database connectivity review your users setup in your VM config.yaml file - a solution would be to use `dbuser` (if your config.yaml has it) instead of `root` for the MySQL username in the MySequel setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect using the SSH tab (username/password are 'vagrant') in Sequel Pro. The database input fields have to match the settings in the config.yaml.

If you cannot connect using vagrant/vagrant ssh into the vm type passwd and enter vagrant twice. You've now set the password for the vagrant user to vagrant. This does not affect the ssh functionality in vagrant, because vagrant uses ssh-keys.